# @Autowired annotation is not recognized for repository in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, autowired

I have created a small spring boot project which will do DB interaction, i am using `@Controller`, `@Service` and `@Repository`.

The spring boot main class is in parent package   `com.bisnu.main`, then the controller,service and repository are under the parent package like `com.bisnu.main.service`....

Every thing is fine but while `@Autowired` for repository, its not able to create bean for the repository, its giving error.

```
@EnableSwagger2
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="*",allowedHeaders="*")
@RequestMapping("/TestController")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private SourceService sourceService;

    @GetMapping("/getSourcelist")
    public List<SourceListDTO> getAllTelevisionSource(){
        List<SourceListDTO> televisionSource = null;

        televisionSource = sourceService.getTelevisionSource();
        return televisionSource;
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class SourceService {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository testRepo;

    public List<SourceListDTO> getTelevisionSource() {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 100);
        List<SourceListDTO> list = testRepo.findSourceList(pageable);
        return list;
    } 
}
```

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTelevisionSource,Long> {
    @Query("select query")
    List<SourceListDTO> findSourceList(Pageable pageable);
}
```

I am getting below error,

```
Field testRepo in com.tivo.extract.core.service.SourceService required a bean of type 'com.tivo.extract.core.repository.TestRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tivo.extract.core.repository.TestRepository' in your configuration.
```

Can anyone guide, what is going wrong here.

thanks

Comment: @Repository use at repository class

Comment: i had tried that also, same error

Comment: please share the project structure. @ComponentScan at the application level will this. But if the package structure is correct then it should work.

Comment: @dassum, project structure is correct

com.bisnu.main   --> parent

com.bisnu.main.controller 
com.bisnu.main.repository
com.bisnu.main.service

Comment: Share the @Query . And it actually query which your using

Comment: normal select query to fetch some data

Comment: if you are using Pageable then the result should be Page<SourceListDTO> instead of List<SourceListDTO>

Comment: @dassum its a custom query, if you are using findAll() of jpa repository then its return type is Page<SourceListDTO>

Comment: Yes correct if your using pageable  should use page is the return type

Comment: directly you can use List as return type otherwise Page.getContent you need to do...

Comment: @mohan please share the custom Query

Comment: select new com.mohan.dto.ListDTO(s.SourceId, s.SourceName, t.TvsourceLongName) from TelevisionSource t join fetch Source s ON s.SourceId = t.SourceId")

Comment: @dassum, ok suppose i removed the pageable object, then any idea why it is giving error for repository

Comment: As recommended by the Spring Boot team, put your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated classes in a super package that spans all packages. That way you don't need additional `@ComponentScan` and `@EntityScan` annotations. Spring Boot will then automatically detect everything needed, including your repository. If you don't you need to add annotations yourself (which can become cumbersome). If this doesn't work enable debug logging (start with `--debug` or `debug=true` in your properties) to get the full stack trace (could be something that the repository cannot be created).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@Repository` annotation to the class

```
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTelevisionSource,Long> {
   ...
```

And add following annotation either to main class (marked with `@SpringBootApplication`) or any `@Configuration`-marked class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.repositories"})
@EntityScan("com.example.entities")
public class BootApplication {
    ...
```

Comment: Adding `@Repository` to an interface will do nothing. Spring Data JPA automatically detects interfaces extending from the common Spring Data `Repository` interface. Spring Boot will automatically detect the Spring Data repositories no need to add the `@EnableJpaRepositories` and/or `@EntityScan` if you follow the Spring Boot best practices.

Comment: Deinum, thats true, because by default @SpringBootApplication annotation includes everything and my package structure follows whatever the structure you told, but i have a query

i want to create a class which will create entitymanagerFactory and creates the datasource, that time i have used this annotation,
EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef="rcmEntityManagerFactory",transactionManagerRef="rcmTransactionManager")

In this case i have 2 JpaRepositories,,, will this work

Comment: Thanks all,for your time and comments.

Comment: @mohan did it help? If yes then you could accept the answer

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko, yeah it helped,, but in my case...i have created a new class where i have kept all my datasource creating classes and in that i have used 

EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef="rcmEntityManagerFactory",transactionManagerRef="rcmTransactionManager")